# Populate WPF Datagrid using binding (MVVM style)

Tags: wpf, wcf, entity-framework, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I'm hoping somebody will direct me to the right path for my problem.

I followed a [series of videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g53__vPihFY) from Rainer Stropek on his youtube channel about "MVVM in WPF and Silverlight" two years ago.
He showed a very clear cut separation of concerns using the MVVM model. I've got it all working.

Now my problem is when I've to display data from multiple entities. For example. I've 2 tables (Jobs and Statuses).

Jobs Table
jobId, jobNo, jobDate, jobStatus =>(Primary Key of Statuses Table)

Statuses Table
statusId, statusCaption

If i want to display all the Jobs on a datagird and replace the jobStatus with its respective statusCaption, how do i go about writing the ServiceContract and/or OperationContract to expose this data from the wcf service to be accessed by the ViewModel to populate and update the datagrid.

**Few More Details**

I created a method "GetAllJobs" in the WCF (Decorated with "OperationContract"), which returns an IEnumerable. It is beacuse the returning Type will be anonymous if i'm to select fields from two entities.

```
[OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<Object> GetAllJobs()
    {
        using (var context = new logisticDBEntities())
        {

            var result = context.Jobs
                .Select(job => new{
                    j = job,
                    jobStatus = job.Status.statusCaption}).ToList();
            return result;
        }
```

On my ViewModel i created an Objs property to impleiment the INotifyedPropertyChanged and also a refreshAllJobs method to update the datagrid on the view

```
    private PMServiceClient serviceClient =
    new PMServiceClient();

public MaintenanceFormViewModel()
{
    this.RefreshAllJobs();
}

private IEnumerable<Job> jobs;
public IEnumerable<Job> Jobs
{
    get
    {
        return this.jobs;
    }

        set
        {
            this.jobs = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Jobs");
        }
}

private void RefreshAllJobs()
{
    this.serviceClient.GetAllJobsCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Objs = e.Result;
        };
        this.serviceClient.GetAllJobsAsync();
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

On the View i have the DataGrid Binding to the respective properties

```
                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Objs}" Margin="10,10,6,6">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=jobNo}" Header="Job #" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=statusCaption}" Header="Status" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=jobDate}" Header="Date" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Most likely, you will just want to return the data you want from the database, meaning that the WCF service will return the data that has already been retrieved using an appropriate query in the database.

Comment: i wrote a method decorated with "OperationContact" in WCF "GetAllJobs" and, since i need to return statusCaption from Statuses Table along with the Jobs Table fields, created an anonymous type and returned it to the viewmodel as an Object.

then i wrote the necessory properties in the viewmodel class to expose it to the view. BUT when i run i get an Exxeption "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

Comment: I've included more details...

Comment: Is this a WPF question? Or is it a WCF question? If you have two questions, you should break them apart and ask them as two separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I hope you will find useful:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillDataGrid();
        }

        private void FillDataGrid()
        {
            Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            client.GetAllEmpCompleted += new
                EventHandler<GetAllEmpCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetAllEmpCompleted);
            client.GetAllEmpAsync();
        }

        void client_GetAllEmpCompleted(object sender, GetAllEmpCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridTest.ItemsSource = e.Result;

        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://chandradev819.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/easiest-way-to-consume-wcf-service-and-fill-datagrid-from-database-in-silverlight/